# POSTされた値で新規レコードを追加したい。

Tags: php, mysql

下記insert_member.phpのエラーログで、108行目近辺に記述ミスがないかを探してますが、何が間違っているのかが何度確認しても掴めませんのでどなたかご回答して下さいませんか。

また、効率的にエラーを見つけるツールや方法などありましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラーログ

```
   [02-Aug-2018 05:14:53 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/insert_member.php on line 108
```

insert_member.php

```
<?php
    require_once("util.php");
     $gobackURL = "insertform.html";

     //文字エンコードの検証
     if (!cken($_POST)) {
        header("Location:{$gobackURL}");
        exit();
     }

     //簡単なエラー処理
     $errors = [];
     if(!isset($_POST[ "name" ]) || ($_POST[ "name" ]==="")){
        $errors[] = "名前が空です。";
    }
     if (!isset($_POST[ "age" ]) || (!ctype_digit($_POST[ "age" ] ))){
        $errors[] = "年齢には数値を入れてください。";
    }
     if (!isset($_POST[ "sex" ]) || !in_array($_POST[ "sex" ] , ["男","女"] )) {
        $errors[] = "性別が男または女ではありません。";
    }

     //エラーがあった時
      if (count($errors)>0){
          echo '<ol class="error">';
          foreach ($errors as $value) {
              echo "<li>", $value , "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ol>";
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<a href=", $gobackURL, ">戻る</a>";
        exit();
        }

      //データベースユーザ
        $user = 'root';
        $password = 'root';
        //利用するデータベース
        $dbName = 'personal';
        //MySQLサーバ
        $host = 'localhost:3306';
        //MySQLのDSN文字列
        $dsn ="mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbName};charset=utf8";
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>レコード追加</title>
    <link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../../css/tablestyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
       <?php
       $name = $_POST[ "name" ];
       $age = $_POST[ "age" ];
       $sex = $_POST[ "sex" ];   
       //MySQLデータベースに接続する
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
            //プリペアドステートメントのエミュレーションを無効にする
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            //例外がスローされる設定にする
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            //SQL文を作る
            $sql = "INSERT INTO member (name, age, sex) VALUE (:name, :age, :sex)";
            //プリペアドステートメントを作る
            $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            //プレースホルダに値をバインドする
            $stm->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stm->bindValue(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(':sex', $sex, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            //SQL文を実行する
            if ($stm->execute()); {
            //レコード追加後のレコードリストを取得する
            $sql= "SELECT * FROM member";
             //プリペアドステートメントを作る
            $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            //SQL文を実行する
            $stm->execute(); 
            //結果の取得(連想配列で受け取る)
            $result = $stm->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //テーブルのタイトル行
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<thead><tr>";
            echo "<th>","ID","</th>";
            echo "<th>","名前","</th>";
            echo "<th>","年齢","</th>";        
            echo "<th>","性別","</th>";
            echo "</tr></thead>";
            //値を取り出して行に表示する
            echo "<tbody>";
            foreach ($result as $row) {
             //1行ずつテーブルに入れる
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>", es($row[ 'id' ]), "</td>";
            echo "<td>", es($row[ 'name' ]), "</td>";
            echo "<td>", es($row[ 'age' ]), "</td>";
            echo "<td>", es($row[ 'sex' ]), "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody>!";
            echo "</table>";
            } else {
            echo '<span class="error">追加エラーがありました。</span><br>';
          };
          } catch (Exception $e) {  
                    echo '<span class="error">エラーがありました。</span><br>';
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
        <hr>
         <p><a href="<?php echo $gobackURL ?>">戻る</a></p> 
    </div>
    </body>        
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 効率的にエラーを見つけるツールや方法などありましたら

エラーが何か表示された=即「分からない」で済ませず、エラーメッセージをよく読みましょう。エラーメッセージはいじわるで表示されているわけではなく、**必ず意味があります**。

今回ならエラーメッセージで「108行目付近」「elseに関する場所」とあたりがついていますよね？
ファイル名や行数の部分を除いた箇所をそのままgoogle等で検索したり、英和翻訳するだけでもヒントが見つかる場合があります。

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) 
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/insert_member.php on line 108
```

---

プログラムの構文をハイライトしてくれるエディタを使用しましょう。あわせてインデントも揃えることで小さなミスに気づきやすくなります。

---

HTMLやJavaScriptを埋め込んでいる場合等はうまくいかないかもしれませんが、PHPならいきなりブラウザから実行するのではなく、文法チェックも心がけましょう。

```
$ php -l FILE.php
```

参考：
[php_check_syntax — 指定したファイルの文法チェック（と実行）を行う](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.php-check-syntax.php)

---

質問を行うこと自体は否定しませんが、他人に聞くより先にまずは自身で調べる癖をつけることを強くおすすめします。

Comment: 最後の部分について、つまり「調べる癖をつける」ことも効率的にエラーの原因を見つける方法ということですよね。調べることが大事だというのは質問しないとなかなか分からないことだと思います :) もっと言うと「どうやって調べるのか」もなかなか分かりにくいポイントでしょう。エラーメッセージで検索するというのは強力な手段のひとつですが、今回の場合は「if～else のまわりに何かエラーがある」ということ以上の情報を検索のみから知るのは難しいのではないかと思います。というわけで結果的に今回は「質問する」ということも効率的にエラー原因を見つける方法になったようですね。

Answer (score 2):

78行目の

```
if ($stm->execute()); {
```

のセミコロンを外して

```
if ($stm->execute()) {
```

にしてみてください。

78行目のif文にセミコロンがついていることで、その場でifのブロックが終わってしまい、
108行目のelseがif構文なしに突然出てきているためエラーになっているのだと思います。

余談ですが、しっかりとインデントを意識したほうが良いです。